# sqrt() function not working with variable arguments

Tags: c, compiler-errors, math.h, sqrt

I don't know if I'm missing something obvious, but it appears that I'm unable to compute square roots of a **variable** in C; the sqrt() function only seems to work on constants. This is my code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double a = 2.0;
    double b = sqrt(a);
    printf("%f", b);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this program, I get the following error:

```
gcc -Wall -o "test2" "test2.c" (in directory: /home/eddy/Code/euler)
/tmp/ccVfxkNh.o: In function `main':
test2.c:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Compilation failed.
```

However, if I replace the argument in sqrt() with a constant such as 2.0 for example, (`b = sqrt(2.0)`), then it works fine. Is sqrt() not supposed to work with variables or something?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to link with the math library (use a '-lm' on the command line). In the constant case, the compiler is probably being smart and precomputing sqrt(2.0) (so the code that is compiled is essentially 'b = 1.414...;')

Comment: That's tedious. What about other libraries, does gcc have one option for each of them?

Comment: @qed no, just one : -l. So, -lm selects a library called 'libm.a'; -lfRod0 would select a library called 'libfRod0.a' In fact it has been thus since ancient times of unix before the dawn of gcc.

Answer (score 3):

In case of gcc you need to link the library.

gcc filename.c -lm .

However in case of g++ no need to link the library so this will work fine :

g++ filename.c -o filename
Once compilation is successful.

To run simply enter ./filename in G++.
and enter ./a.out in Gcc.

Answer (score 2):

Use the command `gcc -Wall -o "test2" "test2.c" -lm` which will likely fix this.

This includes the math library in addition to the standard C runtime library. On most systems, the math library is historically a separate entity that needs to be explicitly requested.

Answer (score 1):

Compile with:

```
gcc -Wall -o test2 test2.c -lm
```

You need to link against the math library.

Answer (score 1):

include math library using " " operator

```
#include " math.h "
```

compile program using `-lm` option for inherit math library
suppose our program name is `test.c` the we compile as follow

```
gcc test.c -lm
```

Comment: The `<math.h>` form in OP is more correct for standard headers. Also, `" math.h "` (with spaces) won't work.

Answer (score 1):

gcc does not link the standard libraries by default. So you just need to do this if compiling via gcc:

**gcc filename.c -lm** .

However in case of g++ no need to link the library so this will work fine :

**g++ filename.c -o filename**

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. I think there is some problem with ur math library. Try linking it again and see. Other wise code is completely perfect.