# C programming sqrt function

Tags: c

```
#include <math.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 

int main(void) 
{ 
    double x = 4.0, result; 

    result = sqrt(x); 
    printf("The square root of %lf is %lfn", x, result); 
    return 0; 
}
```

This code does not work because it is taking the square root of a variable. If you change the `sqrt(x)`, to `sqrt(20.0)`, the code works just fine, why? Please explain.

Also, how do I get the square root of the variable (which is what I really need)?

OUTPUT:

```
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$ vim sqroot1.c
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$ cc -c sqroot1.c
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$ cc -o sqroot1 sqroot1.c
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$ ./sqroot1
4.472136
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$ vim sqroot2.c
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$ cc -c sqroot2.c
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$ cc -o sqroot2 sqroot2.c
/tmp/ccw2dVdc.o: In function `main':
sqroot2.c:(.text+0x29): undefined reference to `sqrt'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$
```

NOTE:sqroot1 is the sqroot of 20.0. sqroot2 is the sqroot of a variable.

```
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$ cc -o sqroot2 sqroot2.c -lm
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$ ./sqroot2
4.472136
matthewmpp@annrogers:~/Programming/C.progs/Personal$
```

SOLVED.

Comment: Post how it doesn't work, since it would work...

Comment: That code looks fine to me. What result are you getting when you run it?

Comment: You say it doesn't work: what do you see? It should work, although as a matter of style I'd put the result variable on a different line. Also you're missing a / before the final n in your printf.

Comment: how come it doesn't work? prints "The square root of 4.000000 is 2.000000n" for me (http://codepad.org/Mv4NNVFU)

Comment: Please format your console sample to be half decent. Thank you and good luck!

Comment: Accept Kizaru's answer as correct since (s)he did such a fabulous job of guessing your problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sqrt() function not working with variable arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533594/sqrt-function-not-working-with-variable-arguments)

Comment: As an aside, the `l` in `%lf` is ignored - `%f` is also a correct format specifier for `double` arguments.

Comment: This code is working fine for me. I am able to get the proper sqrt. I think u need to revise on ur IDE.

Answer (score 37):

The code should work just fine if you are linking in the proper libraries (libc.a and libm.a). Your issue is probably that you are using gcc and you are forgetting to link in libm.a via `-lm`, which is giving you an undefined reference to sqrt. GCC calculates the `sqrt(20.0)` at compile time because it is a constant.

Try to compile it with

```
gcc myfile.c -lm
```

EDIT: Some more information. You can confirm this by looking at the generated assembly when you replace x with a constant in the `sqrt` call.

```
gcc myfile.c -S
```

Then take a look at the assembly in `myfile.s` and you will not see the line `call sqrt` anywhere.

Comment: If you made the same mistake and came to the same conclusion in your introductory programming course, I'm sure you'd be Miss Cleo too.

Comment: @qed It's not a gcc command or option. It specifies gcc to link in libm.a (or whatever naming convention is used). For more info:  http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
root@bt:~/Desktop# gcc -lm sqrt.c -o sqrt
root@bt:~/Desktop# ./sqrt
The square root of 4.000000 is 2.000000n
root@bt:~/Desktop#
```