# C - Undefined reference to 'sqrt'

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C programming sqrt function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120592/c-programming-sqrt-function)

i'm facing a weird problem in C. I've included the  library in the header, and for example the `pow(x,n)` function works as well.
On the other hand ,the next code does does not run at all:

```
float calcArea(double edgeA){
    double s=edgeA;
    float area = sqrt(s);
    return area;
}
```

But when I change `sqrt(s)` to `sqrt(45)` (or any other natural number) it doesn't make any problem.
I've also checked the `sqrt()` function more few times, and it's still doesn't as long as the argument is a variable.

Any suggestion for solving this problem will be helpful,
Thanks in advance

**EDIT : I'm using Eclipse**

Comment: This is definitely a dupe. But I don't have the target off the top of my head...

Comment: @Mysticial http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533594/sqrt-function-not-working-with-variable-arguments

Answer (score 4):

You should tell the compiler to link the math library. On Linux, you should compile with

```
   gcc -Wall -g yoursource.c -o yourprog -lm
```

The order of arguments to `gcc` is important: first the source files, then the object files, then the libraries from higher-level to lower-level.

As to why the error don't happen if using `sqrt(42)` it is because `gcc` might constant-fold and inline it.

Comment: I'm working on windows , how could I link the compiler with the math library ? Thanks !

Comment: It is compiler specific, and I can't give details. I never used Windows. BTW, you may find interesting to use GNU/Linux: all programs are free software, and you can study their source code and improve them.

Answer (score 3):

you should link the math library when compiling

```
-lm
```

You didn't say which compiler you were using, but for visual studio you can try the following:

http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/settings_vc10.html#link

Edit: For eclipse see the [HELP](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.cdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fcdt_u_prop_general_pns_lib.htm)