# Turbo C compiler issue, sqrt() function not working with variable arguments

Tags: c, turbo-c, math.h, sqrt

I searched the question similar to my problem [Similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533594/sqrt-function-not-working-with-variable-arguments). But my problem is when using Turbo C compiler v3.0. Should I have to do some additional work for math.h file? please help.

```
int main (void){
    double result, a;
    clrscr();
    printf("Enter a # for square root.\n");
    scanf("%f",&a);
    printf("a = %f\n",a);
    result = sqrt(a);
    printf("a = %f  and square root is %f\n",a, result);
    getch();
    return 0;
    }
```

The Output is like this:

Enter a # for square root.

**64**

a = 0.000000

a = 0.000000 and square root is 0.000000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `scanf()`, `%f` is for `float`. You need to use `%lf` for `double`:

```
printf("Enter a # for square root.\n");
scanf("%lf",&a);
```

This is in contrast to `printf()` where type-promotion allows `%f` to be used for both `float` and `double`.

Comment: Ok when I used data type float instead of double as suggested by @Emil Dumbazu, it works fine. Can you please explain why. Thank you

Comment: It works on my machine with just that change. Can you elaborate on what's wrong now?

Comment: Its the same problem. I mean it gave me the same result before. But when I changed data type, it work fine.

Comment: That's strange, you're using `%lf` right? It works fine in MSVC. Though I don't have Turbo C to try and repro your issue.

Comment: @Mysticial ok I did this. I am really new to programming and to stackoverflow as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
   scanf("%lf",&a);
```

or change the variable a to float:

```
 float a;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, the first option did not worked, but I used second one "float a", it works fine

Answer (score 2):

In addition to using `"%lf"` as the `scanf` format, you need to have

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h> /* I think */
```

The last one is for the `clrscr()` and `getch()` calls; they're non-standard, but I *think* they're declared in `<conio.h>`.

Without the `#include <math.h>`, the compiler is going to assume that `sqrt()` returns an `int` result rather than `double`.

(An aside: Why do you call `clrscr()`?  What is the benefit of clearing the screen before doing anything else?  The `getch()` call isn't strictly necessary either, but on some systems the default method of running a program results in the window being closed as soon as it terminates.)

Comment: Thank you for your explanation .Yes you are right, I includes all you have mention. I also includes math.h but still the same result. I use clrscr() usually to get run or get output on a clean screen. Is there any disadvantage for clrscr()? For getch() ,program get close as soon as it terminates, so I use getch().

Comment: @AbdulAziz: It's poor form.  Can you imagine if every time you ran, say, `dir`, `copy`, `move`, or `ren`, the system cleared the screen first?  Also, if by "program get close as soon as it terminates", you mean that the *window* is closed as soon as it terminates, then run it through a command prompt window instead of double-clicking on some .exe file.

Comment: @Keith Thank you for your guidance, but I am using Turbo C v3.0. So I have to access with 'RUN' command.

Comment: @AbdulAziz: You should be able to execute the program from a command prompt, but that's admittedly less convenient.

Comment: @Keith Thompson can you direct me how to execute the program in command prompt, or give me any link explaining it.

Comment: @AbdulAziz: It depends on where TurboC places executables.  Someone else can probably answer better than I can.  What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: @KeithThompson i am using windows 7

Comment: @AbdulAziz: Press the Windows key, then click "Command Prompt" at the top of the start menu.  `cd` to the directory where TurboC placed your executable (I don't know where that would be).  Type the name of the executable to run it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable `a` in float and variable `result` in double, and use `math.h` header file.
And use to take input `("%f", &a);` for taking input
And then `result = sqrt(a);`
and print result in `"%lf"` format
it works perfectly in turbo c