# c code doesnt work on turbo c++ with the float numbers

Tags: c, types, floating-point, codeblocks, turbo-c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
    double r,d,x,y,pi;

    clrscr();
    printf("Input the value of r and degree: ");
    //scanf("%f",&r);
    //scanf("%f",&d);

    r = 12;
    d = 195;
    pi = 3.14;
    x = r * cos(d * pi/180);
    y = r * sin(d * pi/180);

    printf("The polar form is: (%f,%f)", x, y);
    getch();
}
```

In the 1st case with defined values of r and d the output comes correct but in 2nd case when I give the input the output doesn't match with the original answer. The code worked on codeblocks but isn't working on turbo c++.

what am I doing wrong in turbo c++?

Comment: Try '%lf' as a format specifier for double.

Comment: Using turbo c++. Also, asking a `c` question while using turbo c++.

Comment: This should say `Cartesian` instead of `polar`.

Comment: Not testing the return value from scanf() is **always a bug**.

Comment: `math.h` has a define for `M_PI` which is slightly more accurate than `3.14`.

Comment: Are you expecting both values to be entered on the same line?

Comment: @user3386109 No, there's no `M_PI` macro in C up to and including C11. That's an extension of your implementation.

Comment: Why are you using Turbo c++?

Comment: Please review [Ask] and [MCVE]. We can only guess what "isn't working on turbo c++" actually means, but @MartinJames managed to spot one thing wrong with your code.  The fact you claim it worked in CodeBlocks seems a bit suspect to me.

Comment: You will need to use `%lf` for both the `scanf` AND `printf` with TurboC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mis-matched format specifier.  Use `"%lf"` with a `double *`

```
double r,d,x,y,pi;
...
//scanf("%f",&r);
//scanf("%f",&d);
scanf("%lf",&r);
scanf("%lf",&d);
```

---

Better codes checks for success before using `r`.

```
if (scanf("%lf",&r) != 1) Handle_Error();
```

---

Output is *Cartesian* coordinates. [@Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48243253/c-code-doesnt-work-on-turbo-c-with-the-float-numbers/48270144#comment83469263_48243253).  I'd also recommend a `'\n'`.

```
// printf("The polar form is: (%f,%f)", x, y);
printf("The Cartesian form is: (%f,%f)\n", x, y);
```

---

It appears Turbo-C [requires](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9051764/2410359) `"l"` when printing `double`, so use

```
printf("The Cartesian form is: (%lf,%lf)\n", x, y);
```

---

Little reason to use a low precision `pi`.  Suggest

```
pi = acos(-1.0);
```

Comment: You'll need `"%lf"` with turbo-c for the printf as well.

Comment: @MichaelPetch  Any reference to support that?  Sure it is not optional?

Comment: Personal experience from 30 years ago and the fact I tested it out a couple days ago to see what the OP was seeing. When the `scanf` was changed to `%lf` the results were incorrect until they were also made `%lf`. I'll see if I can find anything in my old Turbo-C reference books about it.

Comment: @MichaelPetch [Turbo C®
Reference Guide
Version 2.0](https://ia801902.us.archive.org/5/items/bitsavers_borlandturReferenceGuide1988_19310204/Turbo_C_Version_2.0_Reference_Guide_1988.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

In:

```
//scanf("%f",r);
//scanf("%f",d);
```

You need to pass the addresses of the variables, &r and &d.

Comment: That would be one part of the problem if it weren't that the code shows `&r` in use.  Another part is the format string used.

Comment: @Jens: Agreed; I was editing my comment when you commented on it.